# Android - Which method is suitable for implementing getDefaultSharedPreference()?

Tags: android, methods, sharedpreferences

I just want to know, if i have a `Default SharedPreference` then where should I read them? In `onResume()` or `onStart()`?

And where should I make a check that preferences has been changed or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just want to know, if i have a Default SharedPreference then where should i read them?

It depends on your needs. Usually, in `onCreate()`.

> and where should i made a check that
>   preferences has been changed or not?

You should have an [`onSharedPreferenceChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener%28android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener%29) in your application.